# GCC error message after installing OSX Yosemite on Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, haskell, gcc, ghc

Since I updated my Macbook to OSX Yosemite, I've getting the following warning from gcc:

```
gcc: warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘14.0.0
```

This shows anytime I use GHC to compile a Haskell program. The compiling process doesn't fail. I've already installed `xcode-select`. How can I get rid of that message?

Comment: could be an error in the way they typed the kernel version...

Comment: Have you installed the developer command line tools for Yosemite (10.10)?